# How do I create a custom onEnter event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I would like to create a custom event in jQuery that captures ENTER onkeypress events, so that I would not have to code this way every time:

```
if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    // event code here
}
```

In other words, I would like to be able to code like this:

```
$("selector").bind("enter", function(){
    // event code here
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modern jQuery (1.7 and up) uses [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind event handlers:

```
// delegate binding - replaces .live() and .delegate()
$(document.body).on("keyup", ":input", function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13)
    $(this).trigger("enter");
});

// direct binding - analogous to .keyup()
$(":input").on("keyup", function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13)
    $(this).trigger("enter");
});
```

Older versions of jQuery use one of the following methods. You could have a single [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) event handler for all elements.  Then use that to trigger your custom event, like this:

```
$(document.body).delegate(":input", "keyup", function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13)
    $(this).trigger("enter");
});
```

Not for any `:input` element you could do exactly what you have:

```
$("selector").bind("enter", function(){
   //enter was pressed!
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ucnkS/).

Comment: Thanks! also, first time I hear of jsfiddle.com. very convenient.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("selector").keyup(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $(this).trigger("enter");
  }
}).bind("enter", function () {
  // event code here
});
```

It is a good idea to use namespaced event names, to reduce the chance of accidentally clashing with other jQuery code that uses custom events. So instead of `"enter"` you could use `"enter.mywebapp"` or something similar. The makes the more sense the more custom events you use.

Comment: namespaces come *after* the event name, e.g. `"enter.mywebapp"` :)